# How to convert image from tensor(image_dataset_from_directory) to array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm making a neural network and creating an image dataset

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
  root_dir,
  batch_size=5,
  image_size=(200, 200),
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=1337,
  label_mode=None,)
```

Then, using "map", I process images to create a dataset, I want to convert the image into an array and change some of its elements, then again convert it to an image and return

```
def img_input(input):  
  # here I am trying to convert an image to an array but the format is tensor
  input = tf.image.rgb_to_yuv(input)
  last_dimension_axis = len(input.shape) - 1
  y, u, v = tf.split(input, 3, axis=last_dimension_axis)
  return y

def img_output(input):
  input = tf.image.rgb_to_yuv(input)
  last_dimension_axis = len(input.shape) - 1
  y, u, v = tf.split(input, 3, axis=last_dimension_axis)
  return y

train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x: (img_input(x), img_output(x)))
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=32)
```

If there are options, please write, I will answer what functions I tried
Also, if there is another solution, I will also be grateful to read

Comment: alalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()`, `print(type())`, etc to see what you have in variables. Maybe it helps to see what you can do with values.